# Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, render})

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-dom

### Error handling and alerts in React

When I bring the `<Alert />` to the main app component just below the `<Header />` tag, as soon as the component mounts it throws this error.

While I remove the `<Alert />` from the main app component, it works fine.
This is how the browser renders properly before I brought the `<Alert />` to the main app component,
 [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubkD7.png).

Here is the snippet of code that works earlier:

```
class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate} {...alertOptions}>
                <Fragment>
                    <Header />
                    <div className="container">
                        <Dashboard />
                    </div>
                </Fragment>
            </AlertProvider>
        </Provider>
    )
}
```

}

I expect to get the proper alert message snippets in the browser. However, nothing gets rendered in the browser after I tried to use the third party package called `react-alert` from [this](https://github.com/schiehll/react-alert) Github repository.

Below is the snippet of the code that failed with an error in the console.

```
class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate} {...alertOptions}>
                <Fragment>
                    <Header />
                    <Alerts />
                    <div className="container">
                        <Dashboard />
                    </div>
                </Fragment>
            </AlertProvider>
        </Provider>
    )
}
```

Here is my Alerts.js component:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { withAlert } from 'react-alert';
export class Alerts extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.alert.show('It Works');
    }
    render() {
        return <Fragment />;
    }
}
export default withAlert(Alerts);
```

The given error has seen in the console: [Error in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLeRK.png)

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Please, provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem you are facing so that we can help you.

Comment: when does the error occur?

Comment: @JuniusL. Now I think you can figure out what happens exactly. I have pasted the code snippets above.

Comment: post your `Alerts` component

Comment: @kkesley Please have a look. I have edited.

Comment: from the docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-alert, use it like this: `withAlert()(Alerts)`

Comment: Thank you so much @kkesley. I acknowledge my silly mistake. This sorts of support make me worth continue my coding journey.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing your code at Alert.js

**From:**

> export default withAlert(Alerts);

**To:**

> export default withAlert()(Alerts);

Answer (score 0):

usually the error,

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child
>   (found: object with keys {$$typeof, render})

throws when you don't,

> 1. render multiple nodes inside one single parent node(which is not in this case).
> 2. import files properly

if the second condition also passes, maybe should look into the docs of the component your'e using..

Answer (score 0):

Please check the documentation properly. In your code there is

```
export default withAlert(Alerts);
```

But in documentation , to use with HOC you should write

```
export default withAlert()(Alerts)
```